# Updating device detection code for Windows 8 mobile devices - phones and Surface X

Tags: windows-phone-8, mobile, device-detection

I have used the attached code to detect mobile devices before but it is not working (for obvious reasons) for Windows 8 mobile phones and any of the Surface versions. I don't know the proper userAgent for Windows 8 mobile phones and Surface. What needs to change in order to be able to detect a Surface or a Windows 8 mobile phone? Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks a ton in advance.

```
function detect() {
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var mobile = false;
var search_strings = [
"iphone",
"ipod",
"ipad",
"series60",
"windows ce",
"windows7phone",
"w7p",
"windows8phone",
"w8p",
"blackberry","
];
for (i in search_strings) {
    if (uagent.search(search_strings[i]) > -1)
        mobile = true;
    }
            return mobile;
}

if (detect()){
    window.location = "mobile";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RegExp` for search in `User Agent`, this cover 99% of modern devices:

```
/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Symbian|Opera\sM(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|UCBrowser/.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Also you can use service [`wurfl.io`](http://web.wurfl.io/#learnmore) - it will return an object in javascript with flag is device mobile or not. It use [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) cloud with thousands of known UA.

Comment: thank you for the spot-on response :-) wurfl.io looks like the way to go with all the new device types being added such as smart watches and smart tVs etc. One question though - if the client browser has Javascript turned off - specially on Microsoft devices, then this would not work, right? Is there a second line of defense you can recommend?

Comment: I developed for Windows Phone 8+ too. But I don't know about disabled javascript in Mobile IE. There is no such option in it. Also note `wurfl.io` use javascript, and create an object in window scope - `WURFL`, and if javascript is disabled you code will not run and will not use `WURLF`.

Comment: Ok great - I am new to coding for Windows mobile so I wanted to clarify. Thank you very much for the excellent answer and solving my challenge. Happy Holidays !